# Tried to downgrade npm to older version but version not changing

Tags: npm, downgrade

Run

`npm install -g npm@5.5.1` in my terminal but my npm version is still 6.4.1

[image: My Terminal]

Answer (score 2):

did you run this command with administrative privilages. I have never used mac but from my knowledge `sudo npm install -g npm@5.5.1` should work. For windows, open CMD as administrator and then run `npm install -g npm@5.5.1`

Answer (score 0):

Try unistalling the node.js and manually intalling it from [Mac OS X 64-bit Installer:](https://nodejs.org/download/release/v5.5.0/node-v5.5.0.pkg)

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue

It was a problem because of my homebrew

Deleting manually node form homebrew solved my problem,

**This worked for me:**

`rm -f /opt/homebrew/bin/node`

And then installing the specific npm version:

`npm install -g npm@x.x.x`

If it does not works try also:

`sudo npm install -g npm@x.x.x`